# Variable in $_POST returns as string instead of array

Tags: php

In my form i have fields with name photoid[] so that when sent they will automatically be in an array when php accesses them.

The script has been working fine for quite some time until a couple days ago. And as far as i can remember i havent changed any php settings in the ini file and havent changed the script at all.

when i try to retrieve the array using `$_POST['photoid']` it returns a string with the contents 'ARRAY', but if i access it using `$_REQUEST['photoid']` it returns it correctly as an array. Is there some php setting that would make this occur? As i said i dont remember changing any php settings lately to cause this but i might be mistaken, or is there something else i am missing.

Comment: What does $_GET['photoid'] say?

Comment: $_GET['photoid'] is empty as the form method="POST"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise your `error_reporting` level to find any potential source. It's most likely that you are just using it wrong in your code. But it's also possible that your $_POST array was mangled, but $_REQUEST left untouched.

```
// for example an escaping feature like this might bork it
$_POST = array_map("htmlentities", $_POST);
// your case looks like "strtoupper" even
```

To determine if your $_POST array really just contains a string where you expected an array, execute following at the beginning of your script:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And following for a comparison:

```
var_dump(array_diff($_REQUEST, $_POST));
```

Then verifiy that you are really using foreach on both arrays:

```
foreach ($_POST["photoid"] as $id) { print $id; }
```

Comment: Use it in your from entry script as **top-most** command. Then gradually move it to isolate where the array was modified. Only php setting that could potentially introduce it earlier is auto_prepend_file.

Comment: Found the problem somehow i had a statement actually setting $_POST dont even know how that got in there...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. When I should recieve array via `$_POST`, but `var_dump` sad: `'string(5) "Array"'`. I found this happens, when you try use `trim()` on that array! 
Double check your code, be sure you're not doing anything else with `$_POST`!

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array in a string context then you'll get "Array". Use it in an array context instead.

```
$arr = Array('foo', 42);

echo $arr."\n";
echo $arr[0]."\n";
```

​

```
Array
foo
```

Comment: Yea i am not using it as a string i am currently dumping the information using var_dump and print_r

Comment: Then something else is interfering. But this is not a problem with PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['photoid'] is still an array. Just assign it to a variable, and then treat it like an array. ie: `$array = $_POST['photoid'];
            echo $array[0];`

Comment: No, it is a string, var_dump and gettype even confirms its a string containing the text ARRAY.